# Same SelectedIndexChanged function for 2 comboboxes c#

Tags: c#, combobox, selectedindexchanged

I made a same event for 2 comboboxes to populate my input controls so the user can see what they would be deleting or updating. When I made separate events it worked but upon making the same event it does not work. What conditions should i put in the if-statements

on this if condition the **error** i get id **"Index was outside the bounds of the array"**

```
private void BoardComboBo(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox12.SelectedIndex!=0)//error is here
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Users where user_Id='" + comboBox12.Text + "';", con);
                SqlDataReader DR1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (DR1.Read())
                {
                    //code to fill textboxes
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex!=0)//error is here
            {
                //to split combobox values
                string selectedvalue = comboBox1.Text;
                split = selectedvalue.Split();
                //add values on fields 
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Users where firstName='" + split[0] + "' and lastName='" + split[1] + "';", con);
                SqlDataReader DR1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (DR1.Read())
                {
                    //code to fill textboxes
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

I changed the second if condition too:

```
if (comboBox12.Text!=" ")// this works
            {
                //to split combobox values
                string selectedvalue = comboBox1.Text;
                split = selectedvalue.Split();
                //add values on fields 
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Users where firstName='" + split[0] + "' and lastName='" + split[1] + "';", con);
                SqlDataReader DR1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (DR1.Read())
                {
                    //code to fill textboxes
                }
                con.Close();
}
```

I am now getting the same error above when i try to select by **user_Id**

Comment: _"error is here"_ What is the error?

Comment: on this condition i get "Index was outside of bounds of the array"

Comment: Since you want it to do something completely different depending on which combo, why did you combine it?  Also, that has never been the correct way to build SQL for a NET app - it is very error prone and even dangerous.

Comment: it fills the same form one fill it by id and the other by first and last name thats why i thought it would be better to combine the events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the method signature, the `sender` object is the one that's triggering the event, so we can just cast it to a `ComboBox` and check if it's one that we care about:

```
private void BoardComboBo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        
    if (comboBox == comboBox1)
    {
        // comboBox1 code here
    }
    else if (comboBox == comboBox12)
    {
        // comboBox12 code here
    }
}
```

However at this point, you may as well have two separate events. Since there is no significant duplicated code that's specific to the ComboBoxes, refactoring them into one event only makes the code more cumbersome.

---

Regarding the `"Index was outside the bounds of the array"` error, the only place you reference an index is when you split the `Text` property of `comboBox1`. Most likely, the `Text` does not have any whitespace in it, so `Split` is returning a single-item array. Then the problem is when you try to access an index that doesn't exist here:

```
split[1]  // Here you're attempting to access an index that doesn't exist
```

To fix this issue, check the `Length` of the array before accessing indexes that may not exist, maybe something like:

```
// Set the last name to an empty string if it didn't exist
var lastName = split.Length > 1 ? split[1] : string.Empty;
```

Note that you should be using SQL command parameters to build the query string. The way you're doing it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

---

Also, as @Streamline mentioned, your original code has two `if` blocks instead of an `if / else if`. This means that both the `if` conditions will be evaluated regardless of which control triggered the event. It also means that if both ComboBoxes have a non-zero `SelectedIndex`, then *both* the `if` block bodies will run. This may be a cause for the error in the code from your question, and is not likely the intended behavior.

---

Finally, as @OlivierJacot-Descombes mentioned, if no item is selected then `SelectedIndex` will be `-1`, not `0`. This means that when you check for `comboBox1.SelectedIndex!=0`, not only are you ignoring the value in the first (`0`) position, but if no value is selected, then it will pass this condition (because the value in that case is `-1`).

Comment: A value of negative one (-1) is returned if no item is selected. So you should test `if (comboBox == comboBox1) && comboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)`. Same thing for the second one. The error cannot be where you put the `//error is here` comment, because there is no array access there.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Is that possible in a `SelectedIndexChanged` event?

Comment: Maybe this can be triggered by setting `SelectedItem = null;` or `SelectedIndex = -1`. But the original code `comboBox1.SelectedIndex!=0` is most likely wrong.

Comment: Instead of writing my own aswer: maybe you could add to your second part of the answer, that the code of both `if` blocks can be run when invoking the event handler as he uses two `if`s instead of a `if (...) { } else if (...) { }`. That might the reason for the exception as the text is invalid as you already mentioned.